# Disable TFS Check-In Based on Work Item State

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've been wondering if it is possible to deny a TFS check-in based on certain policies.  In TFS I can set that you need to associate the code with a work item to do a check-in, and I can see that you can add a `Work Item Query Policy` that will only allow you to do check-ins against certain items returned in that query.

What I would like to do is deny the check-in based on the state of the associated Work Item.  So if an item was set to "Closed", "Released" or "Rejected" then no items could be checked in against that until the state was put back to something like "In Development".

I'd also like to potentially disable a check-in if the user hasn't done a Get Latest, this is to try and avoid developers not doing it for prolonged periods of time.  TFS possibly doesn't keep a record of any Get Latest requests, but I figure I could possibly check when the last check-in by anybody was done and maybe see if there was differences (somehow use the Compare functionality maybe?)

I realise there may not be anything out of the box to do this, but I don't mind building any custom queries to help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own custom check-in policy to perform logic like this.  You just need to use the TFS API to do the checks you described, and package it up as a custom check-in policy then deploy to your users.

You can read some docs on creating check-in policies here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the scenario that you have I would create a Work Item Query Policy that shows only those work items of the correct type and in the correct state.

That way you don't need to create anything custom and achieve the sake goal.